# python beautifulsoup related problem

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i have some problem to extract some data from html source.

following is sniffit of my html source code, and i want to extract string value in every

following

```
<td class="gamedate">10/12 00:59</b></td>

<td class="gametype">오버언더</b></td>

<td class="legue"><nobr style="width:100%;overflow:hidden;letter-spacing:-1;font-size:11px;"><nobr style='display:block; overflow:hidden;'><img src='../data/banner/25' border='0' width='20' height='13' alt='' align='absmiddle'></a> 그리스 D2</nobr>

<td class="bet" id="team1_27771" class="homeTeam1">Pas Giannina (↑오버)</td>

<td class="bet" id="bet1_27771" class="homeTeam2" align="right">1.65</td>

<td class="pointer muSelect" id="chk_27771_3" num='27771' bet='2.5' sp='오버언더'  bgcolor="f0f0f0"  class="handy handy1" ><span id="bet3_27771">2.5</span></td>

<td class="bet" id="bet2_27771" class="awayTeam2" align="left">1.95</td>

<td class="bet" id="team2_27771" class="awayTeam1">Pierikos (↓언더)</td>
```

so what i want extracted final value is

```
10/12 00:59

오버언더

그리스 D2

Pas Giannina (↑오버)

1.65

2.5

1.95

Pierikos (↓언더)
```

following is my html full source

help me please! thanks in advance!

because html source is some big so i was upload to pastebin.com

http://pastebin.com/Gdun0jhf

Comment: Its a bit hard to see what your question is, Where are you stuck?

Comment: Perhaps you could post what Python code you already have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use HTMLParser

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do a replace on the string

```
html.replace("AAAAAA", "Put what you want for AAAAAA here")
```

and do this for all of the things you want to replace?

Ignore, I miss read the question completely my brain must not be on today

Comment: Er, the OP isn't trying to replace things, they're trying to get the values located in certain places. They manually put in the letter strings in their HTML code as *examples* of what they want to pull out.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works on a basic table:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(YOUR_HTML)
table = soup.find('TABLE_ID')
for td in table.findAll('td'):
    print td.string
```

but it looks like the html you are dealing with is a bit messier. SO maybe it would be best to go after each of the TDs by class name? e.g.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(YOUR_HTML)

#game date
game_dates = soup.findAll('td', {class: 'gamedate' })
for game_date in game_dates:
    print game_date

#bets
bets = soup.findAll('td', {class: 'bet' })
for bet in bets:
    print bet
```